# How to organize Python code for AWS Lambda Layers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working in PyCharm with the AWS SAM and AWS SAM CLI modules.  I am trying to setup a simple program:

1. An Amazon Lambda layer for "ROCFacade"
2. ROCFacade will import Python's standard requests module.  After installing it with PIP, I copied it from the External Libraries/python3.8/site-packages folder (third box) to the lambda-layers subfolder in the second box.
3. I am trying to call it from hello-world/app.py which so far is little more than the boilerplate installed by AWS SAM

When I try to run it, PyCharm reports that the ROCFacade module cannot be found.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t2zP.png)

The error message occurs if I ran it with an "app" configuration or with the Lambda configuration, below.

I have another project that uses the same ROCFacade with a simple main.py console app so the code does work.  I'm not sure if my problem here is with environment variables (i.e., Python doesn't know to look in the lambda-layers folder) or the Pythong app/Lambda configuration.  I am a newbie to both Python and Lambda/AWS development.

Thank you

[Lambda error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSCE2.png)

[Lambda configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2zob.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found my oversight.  In the template.yaml the dev needs to add a reference to the layer in the function descriptor and define the layer.

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Layers: !Ref ROCFacadeLayer
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

ROCFacadeLayer:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
  Properties:
    LayerName: ROCFacadeLayer
    ContentUri: lambda-layers/roc-facade-layer.zip
    CompatibleRuntimes:
      - python3.7
      - python3.8
```